# Vector initialization causing massive memory usage

Tags: c++, vector

I'm having an issue where making some vectors is taking up a massive amount of RAM. As the code progresses, it goes upwards of 800 MB, eventually causing an std:bad_alloc error, and terminating.

I'm using the EasyBMP library which has an RGBApixel defined as a struct of 4 unsigned chars representing red, green, blue, alpha. I'm trying to make an index of sorts of all possible 24-bit (TrueColor) pixels.

I understand this code is excessive, and that there are better ways of doing it. However, this was running just fine before, and I'm not sure if I even changed anything to cause this issue.

By my calculations, this should only take up 64 MB, plus some overhead of the vectors. It feels like it's infinite-looping at some point, but I've looked at this code so long that I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

```
vector< vector<RGBApixel> > dict;
dict.reserve(16777216);

for (color r = 0; r < 256; r++)
{
    for (color g = 0; g < 256; g++)
    {
        for (color b = 0; b < 256; b++)
        {
            vector<RGBApixel> pixels;
            RGBApixel pixel;
            pixel.Red = r;
            pixel.Green = g;
            pixel.Blue = b;
            pixels.push_back(pixel);
            dict.push_back(pixels);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: RAM usage != stack overflow.

Comment: You have 16 million `std::vector` objects... Each one probably has their own buffer...

Comment: You're right, sorry, I fixed the title.

Comment: why would you want to have 16M vectors of 1 pixel each?

Comment: I know, it seems weird. But it's for a project I'm working on. I completely understand it's not ideal, nor should it be used, but this is mostly for my  own learning. And, later on, there are vectors of more than 1 pixel.

Comment: (The previous comment was wrong, deleted) 16M vectors of one 4-byte element each contain several times more overhead than data. Let's see: at least one pointer and one size and one capacity, that's probably 24 bytes per vector on a 64-bit system—even before you start allocating things. Each allocation carries its own overhead, probably around 24 bytes too. So you are seeing maybe10—13 times more bytes than you planned for... 800MB vs 64 mb, sounds about right.

Comment: I usually use something I find very neat. A function I call multi_malloc(size_of_element, number_of_dimensions, ...), ... is a variable number of dimensions. It automatically makes rowpointers such that you can address any element using, e.g. image[x][y][z] etc. Similarly, I use a multi_free, which frees the data and the additional row pointer. If you like, I can post it here :-)

Comment: So if I do a vector of pointers (which point to arrays on the heap), that still wouldn't help too much I'm guessing?

Comment: Vector of pointers which point to what arrays? Of what size? What these arrays should contain? What the entire thing is needed for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, lets analyse the memory requirements of a `vector<RGBApixel>` with one element:

- Payload data: 4 bytes.
- Overallocation by the `std::vector<>` implementation: probably something like 7*4 bytes = 28 bytes.
- Dynamic memory allocation overhead: two pointers, i. e. 8 or 16 bytes depending on your architecture.
- Size of the `vector<>` itself: two pointers = 8 or 16 bytes.

That's 48 or 64 bytes, depending on your architecture.

Now, lets multiply with 16777216. My calculator says, that's 805306368 bytes (=768 MiB) or 1073741824 bytes (= 1 GB).

Comment: I guess what I also find odd is that if I change the for loops to go to 255 instead of 256, it doesn't cross 500MB usage at its peak, yet with a relatively marginal increase, it shoots to 900MB and throws the error.

Comment: That's really curious. I'm really at a loss explaining that behavior: the `reserve()` call should guarantee that no memory reallocation is done in the large vector, neither with 256^3 elements nor with 255^3 elements.

Comment: Thank you for trying! One last thing: what's a good alternative structure to use? Preferably one will minimal overhead I guess. I'm not necessarily looking for continuous memory or anything. But I was using a vector of vectors because 1. the outer vector will grow, and the inner vector was used because it won't always be 1 pixel, later on it will be "concatenations" of pixels.

I tried using a pointer to an array for the inner one, and it still went crazy with the memory.

Comment: The outer vector is fine. The problem is the many small vectors. I guess, your inner vectors will always remain small? In that case, it is likely the most prudent approach to use some sort of linked list for the pixels **with the pixels remaining part of the large vector**. It is important not to use `std::list<>` because it will again allocate memory for each individual pixel. Link the list elements with indices into the large vector, or something similar. Or don't build your giant vector by making the information implicit rather than explicit. Revisit the algorithm you want to implement.